# How can I move an image from one point to another using Android Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm developing a game, and in this game I have to move an image on a Canvas from one point to another in any direction, not just vertical or horizontal.

How can I move that image in this manner?

Answer (score 2):

After getting a math lecture, it turns out that this is easy to solve. First, we need to get the angle which the target will be moving at.

```
float deltaX = targetX - startX;
float deltaY = targetY - startY;
float angle = Math.atan2( deltaY, deltaX );
```

startX/Y can be current X/Y.

Now that we have calculated the angle, we can apply it to the current coordinates:

```
currentX += speed * Math.cos(angle);//Using cos
currentY += speed * Math.sin(angle);//or sin
```

to handle the calculations of how much X and Y will be increased by.
Using speed as a custom variable if you need to have a custom speed set as well. If you don't need more speed, remove the variable.

And to move the object, apply X/Y to the object:

```
c.drawBitmap(bm, x, y, null);
```

**Example:**

```
int speed = 10;
int x, y;
int targetX = 100, targetY = 600;
int startX = 900, startY = 100;
public void render(Canvas c){
    super.draw(c);
    float deltaX = targetX - startX;
    float deltaY = targetY - startY;
    float angle = Math.atan2( deltaY, deltaX );
    x += speed * Math.cos(angle);//Using cos
    y += speed * Math.sin(angle);//or sin
    c.drawBitmap(bm, x, y, null);
   (...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand what you actually want but here's something I've tried.

```
    interface coordinateListener
{
    public void currentPosition(float x,float y);
}

public class ImageView extends View{
    int width;
    int height;
    RectF rect = new RectF();
    float x=0f,y=0f;
    float dX,dY;
    float mStartX,mStartY;
    float mEndX,mEndY;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    TranslateAnimation anim;
    View view;
    coordinateListener mListener;
    public ImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

public void init()
{
    view = this;
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    width = getMeasuredWidth();
    height = getMeasuredHeight();
    rect.set(0,0,width,height);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(mBitmap!=null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,0,0,paint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

    switch (action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            dX = this.getX() - event.getRawX();
            dY = this.getY() - event.getRawY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            y = event.getRawY();
            x = event.getRawX();
            y += dY;
            x+=dX;

            this.setY(y);
            this.setX(x);

            mListener = (coordinateListener)getContext(); 
            mListener.currentPosition(x,y);

            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void startCoordinates(float x,float y)
{
    mStartX = x;
    mStartY = y;
}

public void endCoordinates(float x,float y)
{
    mEndX = x;
    mEndY = y;
}

public void startTranslation(long duration)
{
    anim = new TranslateAnimation(mStartX,mEndX,mStartY,mEndY);
    anim.setDuration(duration);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);

    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            view.setX((int)mEndX);
            view.setY((int)mEndY);
            animation.setFillAfter(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    this.startAnimation(anim);
}

}
```

You can either drag it from one position to another or you can use Translate to move it...like this,

```
view.startCoordinates(0f,0f);
view.endCoordinates(500f,0f);
view.startTranslation(3000);
```

Comment: It isn't an actual view. It is using surfaceview and bitmap.to do it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this library. It should help you with moving, and I think dragging objects like image, etc - [PhysicsLayout](https://github.com/Jawnnypoo/PhysicsLayout). Here you can see moving with Two directions - X, Y. If you want to move including Z, there is only single way to implement it, you should use simple scaling.

If you want something more, there are a lot of powerful and pretty nice Frameworks, Environment.

[image]

Comment: The goal here is to get it to move in a straight line from current position to a target position. Look at it like crossing a square accross. It is a game behaviour and is possible without any plugins or add-ons

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that this answer takes care of physics related to movement, but not how to do this in the sense of automatic navigation over canvas.

Comment: I still trying to understand) For example, using method from View.java - setTranslationX(float x), takes coordinate and just redraw using Canvas. You want to implement drawing Canvas based on position?

Comment: The thing is to move it from point A to B in the shortest way possible. By going directly to the target.