# Putting some indicator around the image in image move/resize/rotate operations

Tags: android, android-image, image-editing

I would like to Scale, Move, Resize Image.  I would like to surround the image with Indicators which guide user what operation these indicators perform  i.e. Moving, Rotating, Scaling.

[image]

I've tried

- Scaling - but it only crops down. No chance to increase length and height of image.
- Rotate - achieved but via inserting manual degrees. That's not a good option in here.
- Moving - as I'm achieving drag on Api < 11. So little bit of difficult. Still no hope in here.

Is there any library which can do me simple image edit [Move, Scale, Rotate]?

Comment: @Pragnani Nah not yet. Increasing the size of image is bugging me as we can't add more size than actual image size insite `matrix.postScale()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using Library : [StickerView](https://github.com/nimengbo/StickerView)**

Its a 3rd Party Library which gives exactly what i was looking for.

**WorkAround :**

Still these answer is half of what I've asked for in OP. Means It ain't surronded by some specific Indicator. I'm still searching how to wrap `ImageView` with indicators and use them for Translate & Resize.

Initilization of Variables inside `Activity` important for Translate & Resize `ImageView`

```
public static final int DRAG = 1;
public static final int NONE = 0;
private static final String TAG = "Touch";
public static final int ZOOM = 2;
public static PointF mid = new PointF();
public static int mode = 0;
float d = 0.0F;
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
PointF start = new PointF();
```

---

Setting `ImageView` to scaleType - `Matrix`

```
iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setPadding(10, 10, 25, 25);
iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

iv.setOnTouchListener(t);
```

---

Adding onTouch Listener to `ImageView` which uses

- 1 Finger for Translate - Drag
- 2 Finger for Zoom - Resize {Pinch To Zoom}

  ```
  View.OnTouchListener t = new View.OnTouchListener()
  {
  public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent event)
  {
    ImageView view = (ImageView)paramView;
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
        mode = DRAG;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

        oldDist = spacing(event);
        Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
        if (oldDist > 10f) {

            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
        }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        if (mode == DRAG) {

            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
        }
        else if (mode == ZOOM) {

            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 10f) {

                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
        }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

        mode = NONE;
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
        break;
    }  
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true;

  }

   private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {

      float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
      float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
      point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
  }

        private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }
       };
  ```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Matrix transaformation to achieve rotating, scaling, and moving....I hope this will help you....

for rotating

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
```

for scaling

```
 matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
```

create new bitmap without changing the original one...like this

```
Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, pow2, pow2, matrix, true);
```

Comment: Yeah Surely I can use Matrix Transformation. I've tried on rotation by adding matrix. But what i need is input to matrix from the indicator. Any help of fetching input from indicator to Matrix would be most welcomes.

Comment: @VikalpPatel you will get x and y co ordinates of the image when you set onTouchListener to it...based on the movement  you can scale, rotate and move

Comment: yeah but in `matrix.postScale()` we can't add size more than image actual size. That'z the problem which bugs me out.

Answer (score 4):

Just check out this image cropping reference :

http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/

For image rotation, just refer to this example; this sample code represents the rotation of image dynamically:

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/rotate-bitmap-image-using-matrix.html

This link is also useful for image crop, rotate and scale:

https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop

Comment: The first link uses a `crop intent` that is specific to `AOSP camera app`, which is not present in all devices, so using that method will crash. Use some library like https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage, which covers it all.

Answer (score 3):

I recently tried the same thing but ended up using a library since it covered a lot more edge cases.  This is a great, and pretty widely used library:

http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/

Answer (score 2):

I think I can help you with the rotation part. I recently made an android wheel menu library. It tracks user's hand motion and rotates the imageview accordingly. You can check out the source to see how I did it here:

https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu

Comment: Thanks brother for your rotation library. I'll check it out ASAP!!

Comment: This library is nice.. But when i create an image view in java file and use this library to rotate the image, i am unable to see the rotation. Can you help me in this one?

Comment: @G_S If everything is set up according to the instructions provided, then it should work perfectly without any problems.

Comment: I created an object and associated it with my imageview. But I am unable to rotate it. Can i know where are the instructions

Comment: This is what i tried but i am unable to rotate the image LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
ImageView wheel_image = new ImageView(this);
wheel_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.wheel);



        final WheelMenu wm = new WheelMenu(MainActivity.this, 12, R.drawable.wheel, wheel_image, true);
        layout.addView(wheel_image);

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not an answer but it's worth mentioning.

Take a look at [this project](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?zfd35b5xcsb27g2). I intend to put it on GitHub but it is not done yet (at all).

There is a button to rotate the image. I am still working on the "save". Many of the classes are taken from the Android source thanks to [Lorenzo Villani's project](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage)

Add to your project's manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="mobi.sherif.camera.CropImage"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

Call the activity using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CropImage.class);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, S.request.cropimage);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the recommendations. I'll take a look at your github repository.

Comment: @VikalpPatel I posted the ZiP file. It is rotating but am working on Saving the file. I am still working on it slowly.

Comment: Were you able to achieve 'rotate' and 'crop' on same Activity then?

Comment: @Darpan I honestly can't remember. Try the project out. Sorry ):

Answer (score 1):

**Bitmap rotation**

```
Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, config);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(mRotation,source.getWidth()/2,source.getHeight()/2);
canvas.drawBitmap(source, matrix, new Paint());
```

**Image Scaling** [Scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930421/moving-an-image-from-one-point-to-another-in-android-on-canvas)

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream imageIn;
String imgPath = "test.png";
Bitmap image;
try {
    imageIn = assetManager.open(imgPath, AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER);
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageIn);
} catch (IOException e) {

}
//TODO: calculate width and height to fill or fit screen
image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
```

**Image moving** [Image in Canvas with touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743328/image-in-canvas-with-touch-events/5747233#5747233)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class ImgView extends View {

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    private Drawable mImage;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    public ImgView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    mImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagename);

        mImage.setBounds(0, 0, mImage.getIntrinsicWidth(), mImage.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }

    public ImgView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ImgView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "X: "+mPosX+" Y: "+mPosY);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        mImage.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can https://github.com/siddhpuraamitr/MultitouchWithDynamicAddandRemove try this code in your project

Comment: This is a great repository! If only it had a better documentation.